# How to avoid replacing my specific path to absolute path from Perl?

Tags: perl

Hi I am writing Perl script like below on Windows:

```
$from = "c:\Users\sy\a.jpg";
$to = "/sdcard/DCIM/a.jpg";
print "adb push $from -> $to";
exec("adb push $from $to");
```

result:

```
adb push c:\Users\sy\a.jpg -> /sdcard/DCIM/a.jpg
failed to copy 'c:/Users/sy/a.jpg to 'c:/MinGW/msys/1.0/sdcard/DCIM/a.jpg' : No such file or directory
```

Why `$to` path change automatically into `c:/MinGW/msys/1.0/~`?

Comment: i guess that ``/sdcard/DCIM/a.jpg`` isn't a valid path on the operating system you are using

Comment: (as an aside: always use forward slashes as a path separator; the script you've shown won't produce the output you've displayed because `\U` is a string escape)

Comment: That and use single quotes for strings you don't want to interpolate.  Either that or forward slashes would save you from the bug with your assignment to `$from`

Comment: @Vorsprung Thanks for your comment. then, how could i make valid path for that ?

Comment: @amon Thanks for your comment. what is string escape ?

Comment: @Miller Thanks for your comment and I tried single quotes for the strings then it works. :-) Your comment is answer!!!!! Thanks :-) I think that I should ask Stackoverflow that comment can be answer. :-)

Comment: @myname.is.yup: You may not realize this, but starting every single one of your responses to everyone's comments with "Thanks for your comment" is incredibly distracting. Just get to the point next time. (No need to thank me. You're welcome.)

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation of Perl's `exec` function:

> If there is more than one argument in LIST, or if LIST is an array with more than one value, calls execvp(3) with the arguments in LIST. If there is only one scalar argument or an array with one element in it, the argument is checked for shell metacharacters, and if there are any, the entire argument is passed to the system's command shell for parsing (this is /bin/sh -c on Unix platforms, but varies on other platforms).

Since you pass a single argument to `exec`, the command gets executed by the command shell. Your version of Perl seems to use the MinGW shell which apparently does some path substitution. To bypass the shell and execute the command directly, try:

```
exec('adb', 'push', $from, $to);
```

Comment: Wow~ great explanation, Thanks for your answer and I tried your advice but it is still not working...

Answer (score 0):

[Miller's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22781290/how-to-avoid-replacing-my-specific-path-to-absolute-path-from-perl?noredirect=1#comment34734540_22781290) answered my question, but I can't accept a comment as a solution, so I answered by myself.
Thanks to Miller :-)

I tried the below code and it works:

```
$from = "c:\Users\sy\a.jpg";
$path = '/sdcard/DCIM/'
$to = "a.jpg";
print "adb push $from -> $path$to";
exec("adb push $from $path$to");
```